# How to remove the overlay shadow in SlidingUpPanelLayout library?

Tags: android, layout

I'm using the com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.3.1 library for my android slideupPanel but I don't know how to remove the shadow when the overlay layout is starting to show.

[overlay shadow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kLN5.png)

Code Layout

```
<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
    xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    sothree:umanoPanelHeight="0dp"
    sothree:umanoShadowHeight="0dp"
    sothree:umanoParallaxOffset="0dp"
    sothree:umanoDragView="@+id/dragView"
    sothree:umanoOverlay="true"
    sothree:umanoScrollableView="@+id/main">

   <!--  Main Layout -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="440dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.00"
            android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="#EBEBEB"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/wandurers_info"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="180dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgProfile"
                    android:layout_width="208dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/colorMenu"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/first_name"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                        android:paddingTop="20dp"
                        android:text="MJ"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="25sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/last_name"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                        android:text="TextView"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="25sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtWandurerDescription"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.03"
                        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                        android:paddingTop="10dp"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="180dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/surprise_me"
                    android:layout_width="208dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#EBEBEB"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/surprise"
                        android:layout_width="208dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="25dp"
                        android:paddingTop="25dp"
                        android:text="Surprise"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="30sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/me"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:paddingLeft="25dp"
                        android:text="Me_"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="30sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/local_history"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.00"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/local"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingLeft="25dp"
                            android:paddingTop="25dp"
                            android:text="Local"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textSize="30sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/history"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:paddingLeft="25dp"
                            android:text="History_"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textSize="30sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="180dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/museums_shops"
                    android:layout_width="207dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/museums"
                        android:layout_width="208dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="25dp"
                        android:paddingTop="25dp"
                        android:text="Museums"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="30sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/shops"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:paddingLeft="25dp"
                        android:text="Shops_"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="30sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/photowalk"
                    android:layout_width="205dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="#EBEBEB"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/photo_walk"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingLeft="25dp"
                            android:paddingTop="25dp"
                            android:text="Photowalk_"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textSize="30sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="62dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/colorMenu"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/book"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:paddingTop="15dp"
                    android:text="Book"
                    android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                    android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
                    android:textSize="25sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtHour"
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                    android:paddingRight="2dp"
                    android:paddingTop="15dp"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
                    android:textSize="25sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/hourWalking"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:paddingTop="15dp"
                    android:text="Hour Walking..."
                    android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
                    android:textSize="25sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/orderTour"
                    android:layout_width="61dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:paddingTop="22dp"
                    android:text="Order Tour"
                    android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewSelect"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:paddingRight="18dp"
                    android:paddingTop="15dp"
                    android:text=">"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="25sp" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!--  End of Main Layout -->


    <!-- SLIDING LAYOUT -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dragView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="290dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@color/colorMenu"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="35dp">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtViewBook"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.07"
                android:text="Book"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtViewHour"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.08"
                android:text="2"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/hour"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.08"
                android:text="Hour"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/walkingTour"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Walking Tour"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tour_type"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.07"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:text="Surprise Me"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/total_amount"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="30dp"
                android:text="100.00 USD"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="45sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorMenu"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="25dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/orderTourtext"
                android:layout_width="333dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="22dp"
                android:text="Confirm Booking"
                android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:layout_weight="0.13" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewSelected"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.24"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:text=">"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- END of SLIDING LAYOUT -->

</com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```

I don't know how to remove it, maybe there is a property for it. When I triggered the sliding Panel the overlay shadow started to show and covered the previous UI. What I want is just to remove the shadow of that overlay.

Comment: It there is a property . It should be mentioned on the github . Check the attributes (attrs.xml) of library .

Comment: thank you for the reply @ADM, I don't were to find attrs.xml because I'm new to android but I'll figure it out at least I have a hint, again thank you for your reply.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel/blob/master/library/src/main/res/values/attrs.xml). You can ask the contributer of that project on github . If the library have this feature or not . Otherwise you need to modify it .

Answer (score 2):

the library now allows you to remove the shadow effect by setting:

```
app:umanoFadeColor="@android:color/transparent"
```

in the XML

[docs](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel)

> By default, the main content is dimmed as the panel slides up. You can change the dim color by changing umanoFadeColor. Set it to "@android:color/transparent" to remove dimming completely.

Answer (score 0):

sliding_layout.setShadowHeight(0);